# Resource file can't be located by eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

I need help badly. I tried to to a clean in my android app Project>Clean. After doing this, All my classes started to have errors. It can't detect the R in --> findViewById(R.id.heightVal); And it cannot locate some other files, xml ids and xmls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you `import android.R` in your activity . If it is the case then delete that line and clean project again.

> R is an automatically generated class that holds the constants used to
>   identify your resources. If you don't have an R.java file (it would be
>   gen/eu.mauriziopz.gps/R.java in Eclipse with the 1.5 SDK) I would
>   recommend closing and reopening your project or going to Project >
>   Build all (and selecting "Build Automatically"). If that doesn't work than try making a new
>   project.

Comment: I thought recreating the project solve the error. But after a few minutes. The errors came back.

Comment: Do you have some problem in xml file ? Please check that . Also make sure that any image resource names are also all in LOWER CASE. I had a capital letter in the name of my jpg file, and it caused the R unresolved error right across my project.

Comment: I have no problem with that. All my resource file are in lowercase and I have no error in my xml files

Comment: The tools in the SDK directory didn't have the permissions to be executed, so it was like the didn't exist for Eclipse, thus it didn't build the R.java file.

So modifying the permission and selecting "Build Automatically" solved the problem.

Comment: Okay I kinda get that. But how is selecting "Build automatically" help build the R.java file when I've been trying to build it so many times? What should I do? And I've already selected "Build automatically" but no improvements.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you if you are using Ganymede and in some other versions of eclipse had experienced similar problems either restarting or doing this cleared it most of the times
right click on your project then click configure build path tick the android file shown there

Comment: have you tried restarting eclipse & adding android to your build sources??

Comment: i haven't tried to add android at my build sources. how can i do that?

Comment: right click ur project u ll get build path _ from there click configure build path click on orde and exports tab -- check android in that

Comment: have you copied the eclipse or the project from some other s/m then try reinstalling eclipse and open your work space in the new one -- and try cleaning the proj once more

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment all the lines in XML file that show an error.
Clean up the project.You can uncomment the lines if R.java has been regenerated.
If the id's are still not detecting try closing and reopening the project.Its weird but sometimes you have to do it.